# how to choose the right datastructure

Tags: java, hibernate, data-structures, orm, enums

I dont know if this is the right place to ask such questions. But worst case I am hopeful I will be directed to the right channel

I have the following requirement

I have a class Basket

```
public class Basket {
  Map<String, String> flowers;
  /name and color, the values are unknown
}
```

I am confused now, about what data structure to use if I have three types of each flower in the hashmap. There is a oneToOne relatonship between Basket and the Hashmap of flowers. What will be the relation f this third structure that has kinds of flowers that are dependent of the keys in the hashmap

If I create an  ENUM for the types, how do I relate this with the entries in the hashmap? which is a String key and String value?

Comment: Your map is defined as having strings as the keys and the data. Change it so that it has some generic object "Flower" as the value. Then, create three classes that extend flower.

Comment: so the class Basket contains a Flower? and the attributes of that class are String name and String color? and then have typeA extends Flower? How do I then define the relationship between TypeA and Basket?

Comment: The Basket will contain a Map, which contains many Flowers. TypeA is an extension of Flower, so TypeA can be placed in the Baskets map "Flowers". Here's an overview of java inheritance. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: can you elaborate with pseudo code?

Comment: Have you read the suggested material yet?

Comment: I understand the inheritance part. I am confused abot the relationship between these sub classes and basket. Ultimately I need to persist this info in DB tables

Comment: actually I missed important info, the type is not 3 but the type is dependent on the keys in the hashmap, I've updated the question

Comment: `public class Flower { final String name; Color color; }` with `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString` overridden consistently. `public class Orchid extends Flower`. `public class Basket { final String name; final List<Flower> flowers = new ArrayList<>(); public void add(Flower flowers) { flowers.add(flower); } public boolean remove(Flower flower) {...} ...}`

Comment: If you're trying to link the basket and flowers in a database, give each basket a unique basketID, and give each flower a copy of the basketID of the basket it belongs too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example of one class inheriting another. If you make a list of Food, you can have Cookie instances in that list.

```
public class Food {
    private int calories;
    public abstract int getCalories();
}

public class Cookie extends Food {
    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }
}
```